# Order of operations between assignment in brackets and operation in C++

Tags: c++

```
prev += prev * (prev = current);
```

Why are the brackets not done first where prev becomes curr, making it curr * curr but rather doing prev * curr and then assigning curr to prev?

Comment: please write the question in the body of the question, use the title to summarize. WHen the quesiton is about code, post a [mcve]

Comment: I recommend never modifying a variable in an expression when using that variable in that self-same expression multiple times.  Put those operations in separate statements on separate lines.  Easier to reason about, which makes it easier to maintain for other programmers or your future self.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4176333/1387438

Comment: *Don't write code like this. And avoid sites that write code like this.* Also see [What are sequence points, and how do they relate to undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/what-are-sequence-points-and-how-do-they-relate-to-undefined-behavior/)

Comment: Notice that code was even UB before C++17...